# Error de conexión al ejecutar PHP ARTISAN MIGRATE

Tags: laravel, composer, artisan

Al realizar php artisan migrate, sale el siguiente error:
He probado cambiar puertos diferentes (estoy con MAMP). He probado 8888, 8889 y 3306. Pero sigue dándome error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Primero, comprueba que en algún cliente gestor de base de datos la conexión se realice, si en el cliente conecta, háznoslo saber para proporcionarte las posibles soluciones.

Comment: @alderson Veo que en el construct del `PDO` no está tomando el puerto que especificas, ejecuta `php artisan config:cache` en consola y después trata de volver a hacer la migración.

Comment: Una vez ejecutado php artisan config:cache ese error no sale. Algo ha cambiado. Ahora al ejecutar php artisan migrate se queda como colgado el terminal con el cursor parpadeando...

Comment: @alderson El comando `php artisan config:cache` borra la caché de configuración de tu proyecto y la vuelve a almacenar, ya que en el error que muestras trae valores de tu archivo `.env` no actualizados a los que especificaste... Dale un tiempo, si se queda colgado, revisa en los logs `storage/logs/laravel.log` y muestra lo que te salga. Aunque  en tu caso si se queda colgado puede que no logre conectar con el puerto que estás especificándole, además, si el puerto `8888` ya lo está usando tu `phpmyadmin` no puede ser que `MySQL` también lo esté usando.

Comment: Perdón, quise decir, el puerto `8888` ya está siendo usando por tu servidor `Apache`, por lo tanto, `MySQL` no puede ocupar el mismo

Comment: Efectivamente Aarón Gutierrez. En .env tenía configurado puerto 8888. He puesto 8889 y funciona la migración perfectamente. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ejecuta `php artisan config:cache` ya que los datos de tu archivo `.env` difieren de los que presenta tu error en el constructor del `PDO`, pero antes que nada modifica tu puerto `8888`, ya que no es correcto que se use el mismo que algún otro servicio, en este caso, tu servidor `Apache`.

Comment: Efectivamente he cambiado el puerto a 8889 y funciona perfecto. Gracias.

Comment: @alderson Como comentario adicional vi que corres `php artisan serve`, como ya tienes instalado MAMP (el cuál ya trae un servidor `Apache`) no es necesario que lo ejecutes para correr el proyecto, mientras tu proyecto se encuentre en la carpeta `htdocs`. Ese comando solo es para cuando necesitas un servidor con ambiente de desarrollo no tan completo o no tienes ni `Apache` ni `nginx`.

Answer (score 0):

Hay que comenzar a descartar varias cosas para encontrar el problema.

Primero hay que verificar la conexion a la base de datos para ver si los valores son los correctos, para eso abre un termina y dirigete a la ruta de trabajo de tu aplicacion, entonces tipea el comando: **php artisan tinker**

y dentro del CLI del tinker tipeas el siguiente comando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro del tinker tipeas el siguiente comando:

DB::connection()->getPdo();

Si la conexion esta correcta, deberia reportarte algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si te presenta una falla, entonces deberas chequear el puerto, nombre de la base de datos y crear un usuario que no sea root con con privilegios y contraseña.

2) En caso de que el reporte sea correcto hay que buscar la falla en el archivo de migracion.
(sales de tinker con exit)

Verifica que la clase Schema este usando el metodo **create** como muestra este ejemplo: (schema puede trabaja con Table para modificar / Create para crear)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3) has un status de tus migraciones, si esa migracion es la unica que esta fallando entonces, el problema esta en la creacion de los atributos con Schema, Laravel tiene una migracion de usuario basica, si te ha funcionado entonces el problema esta en esa migracion en particular.(hazle un rollback y verifica el cuerpo del codigo antes de hacer otro migrate.

php artisan migrate:status

te mostrara las migraciones creadas y ejecutas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias.